# NSClient++: nscp command line checkcpu returns "Counter not found: cpu"

Tags: windows, nagios

This is a fresh install of NSClient++ on Windows Server 2003 R2 (Enterprise x64 Edition), using the latest stable release *NSCP-0.4.1.105-x64.msi*.

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp --version
000000014033F2A0, Version: 000000014033F248, Platform: 000000014033F218
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the *checkcpu* command.  As a start, I'm trying *alias_cpu*, which comes pre-defined in *nsclient.ini* as:

```
alias_cpu = checkCPU warn=80 crit=90 time=5m time=1m time=30s
```

Here's the command I'm running from the console:

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp client --query alias_cpu
e tem\PDHCollector.cpp:185  Counter not found: cpu
ERROR: Could not get data for 5m please check log for details|
```

*nsclient.log* shows:

```
2014-07-15 13:53:11: e:..\..\..\..\nscp\modules\CheckSystem\PDHCollector.cpp:185: Counter not found: cpu
```

Switching out the alias for the actual command gives the same results and log entry:

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp client --query checkCPU warn=80 crit=90 time=5m time=1m time=30s
e tem\PDHCollector.cpp:185  Counter not found: cpu
ERROR: Could not get data for 5m please check log for details|
```

And other forms of the command name *checkcpu* and *check_cpu* also give the same results:

```
nscp client --query checkcpu warn=80 crit=90 time=5m time=1m time=30s
nscp client --query check_cpu warn=80 crit=90 time=5m time=1m time=30s
```

Things seem to be configured correctly:

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp sys --validate
Listing configured counters
---------------------------
cpu = \238(_total)\6: ok-rate(0)
memory commit bytes = \4\26: ok(1.14462e+009)
memory commit limit = \4\30: ok(4.16999e+010)
uptime = \2\674: ok(680227)
---------------------------
Listed 4 of 4 counters.
```

And I can query other counters:

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp client --query checkcounter "\TCPv4\Connections
 Established"
OK all counters within bounds.|'\TCPv4\Connections Established'=22
```

**EDIT:**

I found in the document *NSClient++ Reference Manual.pdf* a section on configuring the CheckSystem plugin.  It says that the default counter for CPU Load is *\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time*, and I can access that directly:

```
D:\Program Files\NSClient++> nscp client --query checkcounter "\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time"
OK all counters within bounds.|'\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time'=0
```

Any idea as to what's going wrong with *checkcpu*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure you have this figured out by now but just in case someone else comes by...
I wasnt able to exactly repilcate your issue, as i do not have a 2003 64bit host, however its similar enough that i think it helps.

My Windows 2008 Server R2 nsclient install is the same as yours NSCP-0.4.1.105-x64.msi

```
C:\Program Files\NSClient++>nscp --version
000000014033F2A0, Version: 000000014033F248, Platform: 000000014033F218
```

My config, in regards to your cpu and alias, are the exact same as i have not changed them from the original config either. 
Command running in client mode:

```
C:\Program Files\NSClient++>nscp client --query alias_cpu
e tem\PDHCollector.cpp:215  Invalid frequency: 0
ERROR: Could not get data for 5m please check log for details|
```

I matched your command troubleshooting to your's. With the exception of the error being different my results were the same as your other tests which were not included here for brevity. Now, i found this odd since this client was working fine from my nagios server and reporting cpu stats via alias_cpu just fine. So i tried to look up my error and found this forum post from the nsclient forums http://www.nsclient.org/forums/topic/old-1169/

The important excerpt from that, in regards to using client mode, by Michael Medin himself

> Not sure what your trying to do, client mode is a bit flaky when
>   checking CPU/meme/* as they require the collection thread to be runing
>   (which it generally is not when running in client mode).
>
> A better option would be to do: 
>   {{{ nscp test
>
> …
>
> check_cpu time=5m MaxWarn=80 }}}

Which worked for me. So the answer it seems that the client should be working as intended and trying to run the commands as we both were can have inconsistent and unreliable results.

Comment: That makes sense, "nscp client" doesn't run the collection thread.  I had searched the forums and didn't see that post, thanks for the info!!!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Matt, for determining why *nscp nsclient* doesn't work with the *check_cpu* command.

I found that by changing to use the *nrpe* module instead of *nsclient*, the following command works for monitoring CPU load on the local system:

```
nscp nrpe --exec query -H 127.0.0.1 -c alias_cpu
```

Note that this requires setting *NRPEServer = 1* in nsclient.ini, as well as having the command you're executing defined, for example:

```
[/settings/external scripts/alias]
alias_cpu = checkCPU warn=100 crit=100 time=1 warn=95 crit=99 time=5 warn=90 crit=95 time=15
```